# Good Program example Mongodb backend with Django 1.3

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I am new to Mongodb database. Its a schemaless db and I really want to try it out with django. I have installed Django-nonrel, djangotoolbox. I have done a simple tumblog application but I still dont have a grip over how it works. I also went through mongodb doc. but have still not been able to understand completly. Could someone tell me where I could find some good example for mongodb database -django.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Well MongoDB provides an Online shell to test and see MongoDB working you can test some code snippets there and it is much JSON like code, so that would be easy to grasp

http://www.mongodb.org/ (there would be an option called try it out)

and learn
also The below link might help you.

http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html